# Why the legend moves when I save the fig?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to save a figure. I defined the legend as below:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(handles, labels, ncol=1, fontsize='10', title='Nbr of \n countries:', bbox_to_anchor=(0.83, 0.4))
```

You can see below what is displayed on my notebook:

[image]

Then, I try to save the fig:

```
fig.savefig(os.path.join(path_img, 'Fig1.png'), dpi=600)
fig.savefig(os.path.join(path_img, 'Fig1.pdf'))
```

Both the pdf and png appear with a legend which has moved:

[image]

I wonder if anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is too use "bbox_inches='tight'" when saving the figure:

```
    fig.savefig(os.path.join(path_img, 'name_fig.pdf'), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Keep titles and legend at their right place!

Answer (score 0):

it's just a guess, but maybe try to also specify the `loc` (e.g. the starting-point from where your `bbox_to_anchor` is measured) explicitly, something like:

```
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=....)
```

Comment: @JeanS ok... then let's try another guess... do you specify the size of the figure explicitly? (e.g. `plt.figure(figsize=(10,5)`)